# make: пересборка при изменении параметра компиляции

Tags: makefile

Одним из параметров ключа компиляции является хеш git каммита: REPO_REV=0x$(shell git rev-parse --short=8 HEAD)
И естественно make не знает, что этот параметр изменился.
Как можно заставить make в этом случае пересобрать проект?

Comment: это строка из мэйкфайла и вы время от времени её меняете?

Comment: Нет. Сама строка естественно не меняется. Меняется результат 0x$(shell git rev-parse --short=8 HEAD), т.е. REPO_REV, который включен в CFLAGS. И хоть он и меняется, make не считает что нужно пересобирать проект

Comment: Мы при сборке проектов используем полную очистку, затем полную сборку. Это гарантирует чистоту сборки. Несколько раз сталкивались с ошибками сборки, поэтому были принята такая крайняя мера. Полностью проект для всех платформ в нашем случае собирается 15-20 минут, для справки. Это не ответ, просто вариант, возможно он вам подойдет.

Comment: У нас полная компиляция занимает меньше времени ~2 минуты, но и это много. Хотелось бы более быстрый вариант. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как можно заставить make в этом случае пересобрать проект?

- если под «пересборкой проекта» вы подразумеваете выполнение каких-то дополнительных целей (например, `clean`, `distclean` и т.п.), то требуется подмена целей. это, в принципе, возможно, но довольно «хрупко» и совсем «неуниверсально».

  с моей точки зрения, такую обработку лучше делать на более высоком уровне:

  - если вы запускаете программу *make* вручную, то, конечно, знаете о том, что `head` внутри репозитория изменился, и требуется указать дополнительную цель;
  - если запуск программы *make* у вас автоматизирован, то проверять вывод команды `git rev-parse HEAD` надо перед её вызовом, и, если он изменился, вызывать программу с дополнительной целью.
- если под «пересборкой проекта» вы подразумеваете то, что всего лишь требуется обновить некий набор целей, то можно поступить так:

  предыдущий вывод команды `git rev-parse HEAD` сохранять в каком-нибудь временном файле, при вызове программы *make* сравнивать содержимое этого файла с текущим выводом той же команды, и, если они не совпадают, перезаписывать файл новым содержимым, а для нужных вам целей указать этот временный файл в качестве пререквизита.

  проиллюстрирую на примере. допустим, у вас сейчас вот такой примитивный `makefile` с двумя реальными целями ­— `file1` и `file2`:

  ```
  all: file1 file2
  file1:
    touch $@
  file2:
    touch $@
  ```

  добавим в начало получение: а) текущего значения `head` в переменную `repo_rev` и б) сохранённого во временном файле с именем, например, `rev.save`, в переменную `rev_save`:

  ```
  repo_rev = 0x$(shell git rev-parse --short=8 HEAD)
  rev_save = 0x$(shell cat rev.save 2>/dev/null)
  ```

  а также обновление содержимого файла `rev.save` в случае, если содержимое переменных `repo_rev` и `rev_save` не совпадает:

  ```
  ifneq ($(repo_rev),$(rev_save))
  $(shell echo $(repo_rev) > rev.save)
  endif
  ```

  затем после умолчальной цели (в данном случае — `all`) добавим файл-пререквизит `rev.save` ко всем целям, которые надо будет обновить после обновления этого файла:

  ```
  file1 file2: rev.save
  ```

  итоговый файл примет такой вид:

  ```
  repo_rev = 0x$(shell git rev-parse --short=8 HEAD)
  rev_save = 0x$(shell cat rev.save 2>/dev/null)
  ifneq ($(repo_rev),$(rev_save))
  $(shell echo $(repo_rev) > rev.save)
  endif
  all: file1 file2
  file1 file2: rev.save
  file1:
    touch $@
  file2:
    touch $@
  ```

  теперь цели `file1` и `file2` (при вызвове программы *make*) будут обновлены **и** в том случае, если команда `git rev-parse HEAD` вернёт новое значение.

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ! Именно с файлом я первоначально и сделал. Но сейчас просто поставил после линкера тач файлов. Файлы "маленькие" компилятся быстро. Единственное этот вариант не работает нормально при вызове запуске компиляции с ключом -jN (N потоков). Зависимости all начинают выполняться параллельно. И тач файлов не отрабатывает!

Comment: Т.е. Ваш вариант не работает с ключом в несколько потоков.

Comment: 1. *поставил после линкера тач файлов* — не улавливаю смысл. 2. *этот вариант не работает* — первый и второй вариант — точно работают. 3. *Ваш вариант не работает с ключом в несколько потоков* — третий из вариантов? в чём именно заключается неработоспособность? приведите, пожалуйста, минимальный самодостаточный пример, который «не работает»